# How do I download python3.6.5 on the m1 chip

Tags: python, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I recently took on a project that required an environment dependency of python3.6.5, which I can't seem to download on the m1 chip
And python3.6.15 doesn't seem to fit projects

pyenv install method is not successful. How can I install python3.6.5

Comment: You may be out of luck since Python 3.6 is quite old, [having reached end of life at the end of 2021](https://devguide.python.org/versions/). It [looks like](https://www.techradar.com/news/you-can-now-run-python-on-apple-m1-macos) the oldest version of Python to support Apple Silicon is [Python 3.9.1](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-391/).

Comment: If you have a project with such brittle dependencies, and you cannot fix them, then your only option is to emulate a legacy environment. I'm sure you can get an older version of x86_64 macOS installed inside qemu somehow.